# How to get equivalent of max() on MSXML6?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, msxml

Evidently MSXML6 doesn't support XSLT 2.0, at least not the `max()` function. I need to find out the node that contains the highest value among its siblings. They are in arbitrary order.

I want the order to remain identical so adding `order-by` and checking `[0]` is out of question.

I want to do this with a single XPath statement. I don't want to call templates or involve any more complex logic than that. I'm sure there is a horrifying MS Scripting Extensions embedded somewhere. Eww.

I thought of:

```
elem1[count(../elem1[@value < current()/@value]) = 0]
```

But it didn't work as I expected (returns the first node always). Any other nifty XPath magic can you think of there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
elem1[not(../elem1/@value > @value)]
```

That is, you want the `elem1` for which it is *not* the case that another `elem1` has a greater `@value`.

Inspiration from [this handy page](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5121.html#d6575e292)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `>` operator, when fed a node set (`../elem1/@value`), compares all nodes in the set against `@value`. This also means that the expression actually should be `elem1[not(../elem1/@value > @value)][1]`, since there could be more than one node with the same, maximum value. In such a case all these nodes are returned, even though you are only interested in one of them.

Comment: Good catch, although <xsl:variable /> selects the first node always when XPath expression returns a node-set. It seems to be automatic.